# Multitenancy With Hibernate and JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am looking for some good references about using Schema Based Multitenancy using Hibernate. I have a requirement of connecting different databases (on the same server) based on the logged-in client at runtime.

I am using JPA.
I searched a lot for references but so far I have had no luck.

[This](https://www.hostettler.net/cdi/java%20ee6/jee6/ejb%203.1/jpa%202.0/multi-tenancy/multi-site/entity%20manager/2012/11/20/multi-tenancy.html#:%7E:text=Multi-Tenancy%20with%20EJB%203.1%20and%20JPA%202.0%202012,over%20several%20databases%20or%20schemas.) is currently what I can find and this confuses me a lot.

Here is what I am using:

```
JSF 2.0
EJB 3.1
JPA 2.1
Hibernate 4.3.5.Final
MySQL 5.6
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Have you read the docs? https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html

Comment: @SimonMartinelli, yes I saw that doc but could not get any idea of implementation.

Comment: this will be a lot of work to explain. you have to inject the EntityManagerFactory instead of the EntityManger and then cast it so SessionFactory and use the code as in the docs